# First div with id + DOMCrawler Symfony2

Tags: php, jquery, html, symfony, select

This is what I have now:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://kovv.mavari.be/rangschikking.aspx");

$crawler = new Crawler($html);

$crawler = $crawler->filter('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlReeks');
foreach ($crawler as $domElement) {
    foreach($domElement->childNodes as $child) {
        $value = $child->nodeValue;

    }
}
```

Now I select the div with id = ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlReeks. But there are 3 divs in my html with the same id, how can I select the first one?

Comment: id must be unique. Whatever, if you want to take first, use break on first iteration in for loop

Comment: thanks, id must be unique indeed but I didn't create the html page ..

Comment: Ok, while you are iterationg div with specific ids, you can use break when first iteration done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the same id multiple times but 'array_shift' is the function you need in this case:

```
$crawler = $crawler->filter('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlReeks');
$firstElement = array_shift($crawler);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a better solution
$first_item = $crawler->filter('.repeated-item)->reduce(function($node,$i){return $i==0;});